# They must let him (to) make his own decision

Tags: infinitives

> They must let him (to) make his own decision.

I participate in voting in social network and 60% voted for not using *to*. But I'm not sure if it's correct to use the infinitive here like we do with

> They must allow him to make his own decision.

Comment: See verb construction verb object bare infinitive [Link] http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292089/explanation-of-grammatical-structure-is-needed

Answer (score 2):

*Let*, along with *make, [have](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/114942/15299),* and [sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) like *see, watch, hear,* and *feel*, can take infinitive complement clauses **without** the complementizer *to*, but **with** a subject NP (like *him*).

- *They let him escape*, but not **They let him **to** escape.*
- *They saw him escape*, but not **They saw him **to** escape.*
- *They made him leave*, but not **They made him **to** leave.*

This is not true for most verbs. In particular, it's not true of *allow, forbid, permit,* or *order* -- verbs similar in meaning to *let* -- which require a *to* complementizer, and are ungrammatical without it:

- *They allowed him **to** escape*, but not **They allowed him escape.*
- *They forbid him **to** leave*, but not **They forbid him leave.*
- *They ordered him **to** leave*, but not **They ordered him leave.*

It's unusual not to allow the *to* complementizer, and it marks the verbs that do it as somehow special. 
Certainly those verbs are less lexical and more grammatical than others, having
started on their journey to auxiliary verb status by taking part in hundreds of idioms.

Comment: Probably mainly because of [He maketh me to lie down in green pastures](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Psalms-23-2/), I feel at some point in the past including ***to*** in your first two examples would have been more acceptable, if not actually *standard*. Is there any reason to suppose there's a general tendency for verbs lose complementizers in this way, or is it just something that sometimes happens, not part of an identifiable "trend" in English?

Comment: In my language this has different meanings. For example with *to* it invokes the indicative mood and without it the subjunctive mood. Does this apply to English?

Comment: @ale - No, "to" doesn't indicate anything about the mood in English.

Comment: What if you removed it?

Comment: @Ale - I'm not sure I understand your question.  Put simply, **whether "to" is there or not indicates nothing about the mood in English.**

Answer (score 1):

It is correct without the "to": They must let him make his own decision.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Free Dictionary, the verb [let](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/let):

> usually takes an infinitive *without to* or an implied infinitive

(emphasis added).

The Cambridge Dictionary also has information about the distinction of [allow, permit, or let](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/allow-permit-or-let).  This also shows that *let* is used without *to.*